# sprintf with dynamic amount of params

Tags: php, printf

I will accept an alternative to `sprintf` only if you explain why it's not possible / highly not recommended

(code below)

i want to be inserting dynamicaly data from my arrays to a mysql DB. i'm also trying to experiment with `sprintf`, wich i recently heard about and want to start using it.

how can i take data from the 2nd foreach and store it inside the query via sprintf?

**arrays** :

```
############################################################
                        $csv->titles
############################################################
Array
(
    [0] => rating
    [1] => title
    [2] => author
    [3] => type
    [4] => asin
    [5] => tags
    [6] => review
)

############################################################
                        $csv->data
############################################################
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rating] => 0
            [title] => The Killing Kind
            [author] => John Connolly
            [type] => Book
            [asin] => 0340771224
            [tags] => 
            [review] => i still haven't had time to read this one...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [rating] => 0
            [title] => The Third Secret
            [author] => Steve Berry
            [type] => Book
            [asin] => 0340899263
            [tags] => 
            [review] => need to find time to read this book
        )
...
```

**Code i'm working on** :

```
$query  = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS XXX (";
$query .= "ID int(11) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,";
$query2 =   "SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE";

foreach($titlesArray as $keyTitles => $valuesTitles){
    $query  .= cleanForShortURL($valuesTitles)." varchar(255),";
    $query2 .= cleanForShortURL($valuesTitles)." = '%s' AND ";
}
$query2 =   substr($query2,0 ,-5);
$query .= "  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 "; 
$mysqli->query($query);


foreach($dataArray as $key => $values){
    ################## PROBLEM HERE ####################
}
```

**one of my attempt** :

```
 foreach($dataArray as $key => $values){
        sprintf($query, eval(implode(",",$values)));
    }
```

**in case someone ask (from php.net)** :

```
    function cleanForShortURL($toClean) {
        $normalizeChars = array(
            'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ð'=>'Dj','Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 
            'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E', 'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 
            'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U', 
            'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss','à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 
            'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 
            'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 
            'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y', 'ƒ'=>'f'
        );

        $toClean     =     str_replace('&', '-and-', $toClean);
        $toClean     =    trim(preg_replace('/[^\w\d_ -]/si', '', $toClean));//remove all illegal chars
        $toClean     =     str_replace(' ', '_', $toClean);
        $toClean     =     str_replace('--', '-', $toClean);

        return strtr($toClean, $normalizeChars);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avoid eval whenever possible. Try [`vsprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php):

```
foreach($dataArray as $key => $values){
    vsprintf($query, $values);
}
```

Comment: omg, THANKS! i love this website, always good solutions! worked jsut fine!